# javascript calendar pop up not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying get Javascript popup calendar control to work which doesnt work.  I am getting

an error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'window.opener.document.forms(...).control' is null or not an object".  Here is my event,

```
protected void Change_Date(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string strScript = "<script>window.opener.document.forms(0)." + control.ClientID + ".value = '";
        strScript += calDate.SelectedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        strScript += "';self.close()";
        strScript += "</" + "script>";

        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Startup", strScript);
}
```

It displays the calendar fine but when I click on the date, I am getting the error and the date is inserted into the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrong brackets:

```
.document.forms(0)
```

should be

```
.document.forms[0]
```

Comment: hi, Thanks for your reply. I tried that too but, still getting an error.  Now it says,"Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'window.opener.document.forms.0.control' is null or not an object".

Comment: then `control.ClientID` is not being converted to the actual form element name. You need the equivalent of: `<%=control.ClientID%>` - hopefully someone else here can help out.

Comment: I think the problem is something to do with Content page. I am using Master page. The parent page for this example is one of content pages. I took out the content page and make a regular page, it works. But, I am not sure how I can achive this with Master/Content page.

Comment: Ah, I got it.  Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Looks like you solved most of it on your own! ;-) If there was a specific change needed to fix this you should consider adding an answer to this question with the solution for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have an element with id "control" in your form?

Your line here is wrong:

```
    string strScript = "<script>window.opener.document.forms(0)." + control.ClientID + ".value = '";
```

As has already been pointed out it should be `forms[0]` instead of `forms(0)` but then it is searching for an element in the form with id "control"

Looks like your `control.ClientID` value was returned wrong, the easiest way to find out what it should be is to look at the actual HTML of the form and find the id of the control you're looking for, and test your method with that, then figure out why `control.ClientID` isn't returning an existing value.